# Align contents of fixed left aligned div into right

Tags: html, css

I have four fixed div in four corners of my html page.I need to realign the top div from right.About 40 pixels.I tried float,padding-right,right.None of it works for me.Below is my html and CSS code.

```css
.top-bar a{
    padding-left:20px;
    float:right;
    right:50px;
    padding-top:7px;
}
.top-bar,.left-bar{
    top:0;
    left:0;
    
}
.top-bar i{
    text-align:right;
    
}
.right-bar{
    top:0;
    right:0;
}
.bottom-bar{
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
.top-bar,.bottom-bar{
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    background-color: black;
    z-index:100;
    position:fixed;
}
.left-bar,.right-bar{
    height:100%;
    width:40px;
    background-color: black;
    z-index:100;
    position:fixed;
}
```

```html
       <div class="left-bar"></div>
       <div class="right-bar"></div>
         <div class="top-bar">
             <div></div>
             <a href="#"><img src="images/social-youtube.png" alt="Subscribe Us"></a>  
              <a href="#"><img src="images/social-link.png" alt="Follow Us"></a>
              <a href="#"><img src="images/social-gplus.png" alt="Follow Us"></a>
              <a href="#"><img src="images/social-insta.png" alt="Follow Us"></a>
              <a href="#"><img src="images/social-pin.png" alt="Follow Us"></a>
              <a href="#"><img src="images/social-twitter.png" alt="Follow Us"></a>
             <a href="#"><img src="images/social-fb.png" alt="Like Us"></a>

         </div>
         <div class="bottom-bar">
             <center><i class="fa fa-copyright footer">2015 All Rights Reserved<a href="#"> Privacy Policy</a><a href="#"> Terms & Conditions</a></i></center>
         </div>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: So you want the right edge of the top bar to be 40px away from the right edge of the viewport (screen)?  Alternatively, you want the content of the top bar to be 40px away from the right edge of the viewport?

Comment: You have to move the top div 40px from right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first guess is that you want 40px of padding to the right of `.top-bar`.

You can do this by adding the following CSS rule:

```
.top-bar {
  padding-right: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

The `box-sizing` property will keep the total width of the block to 100% instead of 100% plus 40px.

Without that, the block would extend to the right and with the padding, it would look like it has no effect.

```css
.top-bar a {
  padding-left: 20px;
  float: right;
  right: 50px;
  padding-top: 7px;
}
.top-bar, .left-bar {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.top-bar i {
  text-align: right;
}
.right-bar {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.bottom-bar {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.top-bar, .bottom-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 100;
  position: fixed;
}
.top-bar {
  padding-right: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.left-bar, .right-bar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 100;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-bar"></div>
<div class="right-bar"></div>
<div class="top-bar">
  <div></div>
  <a href="#"><img src="images/social-youtube.png" alt="Subscribe Us"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="images/social-link.png" alt="Follow Us"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="images/social-gplus.png" alt="Follow Us"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="images/social-insta.png" alt="Follow Us"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="images/social-pin.png" alt="Follow Us"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="images/social-twitter.png" alt="Follow Us"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="images/social-fb.png" alt="Like Us"></a>
</div>
<div class="bottom-bar">
  <center><i class="fa fa-copyright footer">2015 All Rights Reserved<a href="#"> Privacy Policy</a>
    <a href="#"> Terms & Conditions</a></i>
  </center>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks man.U saved my day.Since i'm a beginner to this web design,i don't know much about this.Thank you

Comment: Remember to accept the answer (you get extra points by doing so!) and welcome to SO!

Comment: And one more thing.I wanna show heading above a div.I set the div position into relative and the position of the heading as absolute.But its not working.Do i have to apply z-index or is there anything else i cud do?..I know it sounds crazy without code,but i really wanted to know.Thank you

Comment: @RahisArm It might be easier to post another question with some code, otherwise I am guessing about what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Marc..Yes.But the stack overflow itself blocking me from posting questions.Lemme see what i can do about that

Comment: @RahisArm If your account is in good standing, you can post another separate question.  So far you have 4 questions, so just post a new question and either I or someone else can try to help you.  Good luck!